# Transferring a file from one server to another server, initiated from a third computer

Tags: linux, command-line, ftp, scp

I'm trying to make a site to site transfer with the following configuration. 
I have an old server (server-A), the new server (server-B), and my workstation (wks), on which I'd like to launch the transfer.

SSH key exchange has been done between wks and server-A/B.

Server-A and server-B have no keys exchanged.

I tried the following command from my workstation

```
scp -r root@server-A:/path/to/source/ root@server-B:/destination/path
```

but it doesn't work. As far as I understand, server-A tries to connect to server-B, and as there's no key exchange done, it fails.

Any idea how to make the file transfer work for this particular configuration?

Comment: Download the files to your workstation then upload them to the other server.

Comment: ssh into server A, start the scp on server A (one command). Avoids copying the files twice.

Comment: Thanks but no thanks, the purpose is to avoid connecting on server-A and B, and do it "remotely".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transferring files using a direct connection between server-A and server-B is the preferred method. This is what `scp` is trying to do. The relevant part of [`man 1 scp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html):

> `-3`
>   Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local host. Without this option the data is copied directly between the two remote hosts. Note that this option disables the progress meter.

You're right that without the `-3` option "server-A tries to connect to server-B". My tests indicate that even if server-B allows password-based authentication, interacting with tty (while being asked the password) will most likely be the problem. In such case [this comment](https://superuser.com/q/1347044/432690#comment2018181_1347044) seems useful:

> `ssh` into server A, start the `scp` on server A (one command). Avoids copying the files twice.

After you explicitly `ssh` into server-A, `scp` invoked there should have no problem interacting with tty while asking the password for server-B. Alternatively you can `ssh` into server-B and invoke `scp` there.

If it's impossible (key required, password disallowed), use `scp -3` on your workstation. Obviously this will use your local machine as a kind of proxy, so the data will flow down and up its network connection(s).

Not all `scp` implementations support `-3` though.