# scp transfer through an intermediate host

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I have 3 servers: A, B, C and need to transfer a file from A to C.

`ssh` is only possible from A to B and from C to B (see below), because A and C are on 2 different VPNs.

- A → B
- C → B

SSH is not possible: from B to C, from B to A nor from A to C.

All the examples I could find online were 'jump host' or hop like this: A → B → C; but it doesn't work in my situation because B → C is not possible.

What would be the best way to transfer from A to C in that scenario (preferably using `scp`)?
I think the only way is using some sort of reverse SSH tunnel but couldn't make it work.

Comment: So there is an SSH server on B. (1) Is there (or can you start) an SSH server on C or on A? (2) Do you want to initiate the transfer from A or from C? or from B?

Comment: SSH server is only available on B, so the transfer will have to be initiated from there.
(actually A and C also have ssh server but these are not reachable from B because A and C are on separate VPN)

Comment: (1) The "actually" is what I was asking. (2) Won't have to. From where do you *want*?

Comment: (2) It doesn't really matter, any of them. B probably the easiest as it is directly accessible from anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Preliminary notes

I assume you can `ssh userB@B_seen_from_A` from A to reach B; and you can `ssh userB@B_seen_from_C` from C to reach B. I also assume there are SSH servers on A and on C as well (although for now you cannot reach them from the outside).

`scp` uses `ssh` directly, I mean it crafts an `ssh …` command (and this is not as clean as we may want, see "some insight" in [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1685833/432690)). Setting things up for `scp` means setting things up for `ssh` in the first place.

When following this answer, if you encounter an error or unexpected message, please see "Notes" down below. Some of them address few possible obstacles.

---

#### Basic setup for invoking `scp` on A

You did not tell us your tries to establish "some sort of reverse SSH tunnel" when you "couldn't make it work". I don't know what you tried and how it failed. You are probably able to do this:

```
# on C
ssh -R 1111:localhost:22 -N userB@B_seen_from_C
```

(Note `localhost` will be resolved on C, so the tunnel will lead to C.)

This is the remote tunnel you need. The number `1111` is quite arbitrary (you most likely [are not allowed to use a port with number lower than 1024](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports) and you may want to avoid [ephemeral ports](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65475/108618); and of course the port must be available). `22` is the standard port for SSH (use the port your SSH server on C uses). If you do this right then `ssh -p 1111 userC@localhost` invoked on B will let you reach C.

Still you won't be able to use this tunnel from A. If on C you used `… -R :1111:localhost:22 …` (note the additional colon) then you might or might not be able to `ssh -p 1111 userC@B_seen_from_A` from A to reach C, depending on the firewall and the settings of the SSH server on B (compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1276862/432690)). Let's not do this. Let's create *another* tunnel, from A to B, that allows you to reach the first tunnel from A. This is the other tunnel:

```
# on A
ssh -L 2222:localhost:1111 -N userB@B_seen_from_A
```

(Note this `localhost` will be resolved on B, so the tunnel will lead to B.)

Now you can reach C from A by connecting via the two chained tunnels:

```
# on A
ssh -p 2222 userC@localhost
```

(And this `localhost` is resolved on A, it leads to A; we're connecting to the A's end of the chained tunnels, the other end is on C.)

Then you can copy files between A and C by invoking `scp` on A:

```
# on A
# copying from A to C
scp -P 2222 /local/path/to/file userC@localhost:/remote/destination
# or copying from C to A
scp -P 2222 userC@localhost:/remote/path/to/file /local/destination
```

(Note with `scp` you need `-P` to specify the port, while with `ssh` you need `-p`.)

---

#### Basic setup for invoking `scp` on C

There's a symmetry between A and C in your original setup. To be able to copy files between A and C by invoking `scp` on C, just swap A and C in the above solution.

---

#### Basic setup for invoking `scp` on A or C

You can merge the two above solutions, so copying files can be done by invoking `scp` on A or C. Terminate (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) all previous `ssh` commands we used and start anew:

```
# on C
ssh -L 3333:localhost:3333 -R 1111:localhost:22 -N userB@B_seen_from_C
```

```
# on A
ssh -L 1111:localhost:1111 -R 3333:localhost:22 -N userB@B_seen_from_A
```

Note it's `1111` where previously we had `2222`. The idea is to use the same port number to reach C from A or from B (and the number is `1111`); and another number to reach A from C or from B (and the number is `3333`). So `1111` is associated with two chained tunnels in one direction, `3333` is associated with two chained tunnels in the opposite direction. The SSH server on B will listen on both ports, therefore the numbers must differ.

Then on A use `scp -P 1111 …` and refer to C as `userC@localhost`; or on C use `scp -P 3333 …` and refer to A as `userA@localhost`.

---

#### How about invoking `scp` on B?

The two `ssh` commands from the previous section will allow you to reach C from B (by connecting to B's `localhost` on port `1111`) and to reach A from B (by connecting to B's `localhost` on port `3333`). In theory this should be enough for `scp` on B to easily transfer a file from A to C. In practice `scp` is somewhat limited.

In general, when `scp` is about to copy a file between two remote hosts, there are two ways:

- Traditionally `scp` tells one host to reach the other and transfer the file. The machine where you invoke `scp` may be unable to reach the other host and the method will still work, if only the first host can reach the other. The invoked `scp` executable does not act as a relay.
- With [`scp -3`](https://superuser.com/a/1515716/432690) the invoked `scp` executable acts as a relay. The machine where you invoke `scp` needs to be able to reach the two hosts, but neither host needs to be reachable from the other.

One way or another, if you need to specify two different ports (and you do in our setup) then it won't work with `scp -P` because `scp -P` allows you to specify a single value.

It should work if you pass the ports [in a different way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/678415/108618). Example:

```
# on B
# copying from A to C
scp -3 scp://userA@localhost:3333//A_path/to/file \
       scp://userC@localhost:1111//C_path/to/destination
```

Another solution exists, please read the next section.

---

#### More elegant and powerful setup

`ssh` (and related tools) consult config files (`~/.ssh/config` for user's and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` for server-wide config). Instead of specifying things on the command line, specify them in the config (note: [near the beginning](https://superuser.com/a/1241953/432690)).

On A:

```
Host B
   Hostname B_seen_from_A
   User userB

Host C
   Hostname localhost
   Port 1111
   User userC
```

On B:

```
Host A
   Hostname localhost
   Port 3333
   User userA

Host C
   Hostname localhost
   Port 1111
   User userC
```

On C:

```
Host A
   Hostname localhost
   Port 3333
   User userA

Host B
   Hostname B_seen_from_C
   User userB
```

The commands that create tunnels simplify to:

```
# on C
ssh -L 3333:localhost:3333 -R 1111:localhost:22 -N B
```

```
# on A
ssh -L 1111:localhost:1111 -R 3333:localhost:22 -N B
```

(The port forwardings can be specified in the configs as well, see `LocalForward` and `RemoteForward` in [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config); but this would affect any `ssh … B …` and you may not want this.)

An example `scp` command on A is simple:

```
# on A
scp /path/to/file C:/some/destination
```

And now you can do this also from B:

```
# on B
scp A:/path/to/file C:/some/destination
# or
scp -3 A:/path/to/file C:/some/destination
```

Or from C:

```
# on C
scp A:/path/to/file /some/destination
```

The point is now A and B can resolve `C`, each to a different address, but each address is exactly the right one in the context of the respective client. Similarly B and C can resolve `A`. And if you additionally make sure A recognizes `A` as itself and C recognizes `C` as itself then this command:

```
scp A:/path/to/file C:/some/destination
```

should work on *any* of the three hosts. It will establish some unnecessary connections (like from A to A) if invoked on A or on C, but in principle it will work; it's a universal command then.

There are possible problems, see below.

---

#### Notes

- If you get `administratively prohibited: open failed` while creating a tunnel then see this question: [*SSH tunneling error: `channel 1: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed`*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14160/108618).
- `ExitOnForwardFailure` may be handy.
- Instead of `ssh -L … -R … -N …` on A consider `autossh` [or a service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/423795/108618) to keep the tunnels open; the same for C.
- When using `scp` on B without `-3` [password authentication may break things](https://superuser.com/a/1347075/432690). Prefer key-based authentication.
- There are six or eight possible client-server pairs (A→B, A→C, B→A, B→C, C→A, C→B; and if you want "universal commands" to be universal then additionally A→A and C→C). If you set up key-based authentication for only few of them then some commands will fail or ask for password. Pay attention to what client needs to authenticate to what server, or simply set up key-based authentication for all possible pairs.
- The ports you open (i.e. the listening ends of the tunnels) will be available at least to other local users of respective systems (A, B or C). Each tunnel ultimately leads to an SSH server where one needs to authenticate. Even if a rogue user hijacks the port (by simply binding to it before you do) and your tunnel leads to their SSH server, [you will be able to tell](https://superuser.com/a/1657396/432690) before you send your precious files or request possibly dangerous files. Still, just by keeping the port occupied, the rogue may prevent you from setting things up (especially if your setup is automated and not supervised). Unix sockets instead of TCP ports on B may help, but I won't elaborate.
- IMO `scp` is a quick and dirty hack that stuck (see near the end of [this already linked answer](https://superuser.com/a/1685833/432690)). The tunnels should allow you to use any tool that uses SSH as transport, especially after you move the details to config files.

Comment: Thank you sir for the thorough answer. I haven't managed to make this work yet but I'm sure this is due to my lack of understanding on this works. I'll do further reading on ssh tunnelling to set this up properly. Very helpful answer, thanks again